# My cell in my Jtable got smaller due to large number of column from database

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Hoping for your fast response.. I`m really out

[This is how it looks when i run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuFCg.png)

[this is the number of my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax2yg.png)

Comment: The issue is how to add the table to the frame. First create the JTable. Add the JTable to the viewport of a JScrollPane. Add the JScrollPane to the frame.

Comment: Once you have your JTable placed properly within a JScrollPane as been suggested, and because there are so many columns to your table, it may be a good idea to turn off the JTable's `autoResizeMode`, for example: `jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);`. This will make the User need to use the Horizontal scrollbar to view columns to the right side of the JTable.

Comment: You can also include images directly in the post. This way both images are shown at once and readers save two clicks.

Answer (score 1):

I am agreed with @DevilsHnd answered. You need to set auto resize off and make the horizontal scrollbar visible.

```
JTable.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
JTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```